# $this->config->get()

Tags: model-view-controller, php

I'm reading someone else's code (need to make some changes in it) and I'm stuck at this function. Its probably related to MVC approach and is common on the web (i found a lot of google results) but i couldn't find what it actually does.

I'm guessing it's a standard method common to major MVC-based CMSes/PHP platforms, but I can't find where it's coded or what it does?

here's the code snippet for reference

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($this->config->get($result['key'] . '_status') && ($this->config->get($result['key'] . '_position') == 'left')) {
                $module_data[] = array(
                    'code'       => $result['key'],
                    'sort_order' => $this->config->get($result['key'] . '_sort_order')
                );

                $this->children[] = 'module/' . $result['key'];     
            }
        }
```

I understand that there must be an object config with a method get()

But neither the class that contains this code (class ControllerCommonColumnLeft), nor the class that it extends from (extends Controller) has any of these, that is why I ask...

Comment: Could you start by giving us some context code?

Comment: Is this some specific framework or a library or something homebrewn?

Comment: A bit of context would help very much. What software did you find it in? What does the surrounding code look like?

Comment: I've added the code that's calling this function. I'm sure its not exactly one of the frameworks already out there because I've found no reference to any of it but it's likely that its highly based on one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where it's used. In PHP, `$this` refers to "the current class", so if you have, for example, in the following code, `$this` is like saying "Look in the class `Person` for ..."

```
class Person
{
    public function walk ($to)
    {
        echo 'I walked to ' . $to . '<br />';
    }

    public function eat ($food, $place)
    {
        // Here, $this->walk() calls Person->walk(), as '$this class' is called Person
        $this->walk($place);
        echo 'I ate a ' . $food . ' at ' . $place;
    }
}

$person = new Person;
$person->eat('jelly bean', 'the sweet shop');
```

It can be a little more complicated once you start using `static` classes, but you shouldn't worry about those for now.

Comment: OK. Your class has a variable called `$config` which holds an instance of another class (presumably a config class), and `$this->config->get()` calls the `get()` method from that class. `$this->children[]` sets the array `$children` inside the class you're in to 'module/...'